# Why instantiate pandas.IndexSlice before use?

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

Everywhere I see `pandas.IndexSlice` code (including [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html)) it is instantiated before being used, like this:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, 'A':'B'], :]  # Sample use of pandas.IndexSlice
```

Is there a reason to do that, instead of everywhere using it inline like this:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'A':'B'], :]  # Inline use of pandas.IndexSlice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
```

Doesn't instantiate it. this is creating an *alias*, probably because `idx` is much more readable. but these two are equivalent.